# how to reset stringstream object

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a stringstream object and I am wondering how to reset it.

```
stringstream os;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        value = rand() % 100;
        os<<value;
        cout<<os.str()<<" "<<os<<endl;
        ntree->insert(os.str());
        //I want my os object to be reset here
    }
```

Comment: Do you _really_ mean "initialize"? The stringstream is initialised when you construct it. By definition, a thing cannot be initialised later in its lifetime. Do you mean "reset"?

Comment: Then edit your question to indicate this, please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want a new `ostringstream` object each time through the loop, the obvious solution is to declare a new one at the top of the loop.  All of the `ostream` types contain a lot of state, and depending on context, it may be more or less difficult to reset all of the state.

Comment: That would also mean that it would be better encapsulated inside the scope of the loop, which is always good :) (See "Item 26: Postpone variable definitions as long as possible." in Scott Meyers' "Effective C++"

Answer (score 9):

If you want to replace the contents of the `stringstream` with something else, you can do that using the `str()` method. If you call it without any arguments it will just *get* the contents (as you're already doing). However, if you pass in a string then it will *set* the contents, discarding whatever it contained before.

E.g.:

```
std::stringstream os;
os.str("some text for the stream");
```

For more information, check out the method's documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str

Comment: I think after os.str("some text for stream") os.clear() should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but the code example makes it clearer.

You have two choices:

First, initialze ostringstream through construction (construct another instance in each step of the loop):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    value = rand() % 100 ;
    ostringstream os;
    os << value;
    cout << os.str() << " " << os << endl;
    ntree->insert(os.str());
    //i want my os object to initializ it here
}
```

Second, reset the internal buffer and clear the stream state (error state, eof flag, etc):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    value = rand() % 100 ;
    os << value;
    cout << os.str() << " " << os << endl;
    ntree->insert(os.str());
    //i want my os object to initializ it here
    os.str("");
    os.clear();
}
```

Comment: Clearing the stream's state is anything but trivial: in the most general case, you also have to reinitialize the `fmtflag`, the precision, the fill character, and any state dynamically allocated by `xalloc`.  (That last is very, very difficult.)